# How to Run SSIS package from Excel VBA

Tags: sql, ssis

I have the below code to run SSIS package from VBA. It is running without parameters. 
If I pass the parameters it is not working.
My Code as follows:

```
    Dim Command As String
    Dim Rsvr As String
    Rsvr = "MYVALUE"

Command = "dtexec /f ""mypath\Package.dtsx /set 
           \package.variables[User::myvalue].Value"" & Rsvr"

Call Shell(Command, 0)
```

Please Advice

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of Command when you debug, before the call?

Comment: I need to set the variable value from excel macro this is my requirement. If I hardcoded the value in Package then it is running but I want to use my variable as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the quotes.

It could be like this instead:

```
Dim Command As String
    Dim Rsvr As String
    Rsvr = "MYVALUE"

Command = "dtexec /f ""mypath\Package.dtsx /set 
           \package.variables[User::myvalue].Value""" & Rsvr

Call Shell(Command, 0)
```